# react-native start fails on every project

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been developing a react-native application on my MacBook Pro but am forced now to use my desktop Windows machine. I can't get the server to even start using `npm start` or `react-native start --reset-cache` on this project or a brand new `react-native init` app as well. I get this error message:

I've made sure to run npm install and react-native link

Using:
* node 10.16.0
* npm 6.9.0
* react-native-cli 2.0.1
* "react": "16.8.3",
* "react-native": "0.59.4",

> ```
> npm start --reset-cache
> react-native start --reset-cache
>
> warning: the transform cache was reset.
> Loading dependency graph...events.js:174
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
> Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
>     at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:123:28)
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>     at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (H:\sampleproject\node_modules\metro\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:143:12)
>     at FSWatcher.emit (events.js:198:13)
>     at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:129:12)
> ```

Comment: I got the same issue. Did you resolve it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Does it return the same error when you use `react-native start` or `react-native run-android`

Comment: it does throw the same error when using react-native start

Answer (score 0):

I had cloned the repository and created the projects in the H: drive, but it worked as expected once I ran the projects in the C: drive.